# How can a UserControl be notified when its parental Form obtains or loses its focus?

Tags: vb.net, forms, user-controls

My user control sits on a Windows Form. Depending on the focus (whether it is on the user control's parental Form, or not) I want to do separate things. I know, that I can access the parental Form easily by

```
 Private Sub Rearrange()
        'Obtain the control's parent. The control is intended to run on a Form only.
        Dim oFrmParent As Form = Me.Parent
        ...
 End Sub
```

However, here I am stuck. Although the Form does have a *Focused* property, it doesn't seem to be too meaningful for my purpose, since I want my *UserControl* to react on the Form obtaining the focus from an other arbitrary app, as well as losing the focus to another arbitrary app, without the Form needing to call any UserControl methods.

The question is: how can I be notified when the parent obtains or loses the focus to execute some code?

Comment: Subscribe to the `Activated` and `Deactivated` events.

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks, **AddHandler ParentForm.Activated, AddressOf ParentActivated** solved the problem! (Seems the opposite event is named Deactivate, though, w/o an ending -d. Possibly a bit inconsistent, as there is a method named Activate.). If you bother to make it an answer, I'd accept it as the solution, of course.